# Is there any way to list queues in a rabbitmq via pika?

Tags: python, queue, rabbitmq, pika

I know that we can do this to list queue in a rabbitmq.

```
rabbitmqctl list_queues
```

but how can I do this via pika?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

No.

Pika is an AMQP library.

If you want to manage an MQ Broker, then you need an MQ Broker management tool. Fortunately, RabbitMQ comes with such a tool if you install a recent version of RabbitMQ such as 2.7.1 and you install the RabbitMQ management plugins. That gives you a web GUI as well as a RESTful API that you can use in your scripts.

But it's all outside of the scope of AMQP itself.

http://www.rabbitmq.com/management.html for the management plugin with a web GUI and http://www.rabbitmq.com/management-cli.html for a CLI type of interface.

Comment: so the AMQP protocal itself does not support 'listing queue', right? then, do rabbitmq provide this kind of api?